# Annealing on a multi-layered neural network: XOR experiments

Tags: java, neural-network, xor, simulated-annealing

Im begineer in this concept and what I have tried to learn for a feed-forward type neural network(topology of **2x2x1**  ):

```
Bias and weight range of each neuron_____________Outputs for XOR test inputs
                [-1,1]                           1,1 ----> 0,9            
                                                 1,0 ----> 0,8
                                                 0,1 ---->-0.1
                                                 0,0 ----> 0.1

                [-10,10]                         1,1 ----> 0,24            
                                                 1,0 ----> 0,67
                                                 0,1 ---->-0.54
                                                 0,0 ----> 0.10

                [-4,4]                           1,1 ----> -0,02            
                                                 1,0 ----> 0,80
                                                 0,1 ----> 0.87
                                                 0,0 ----> -0.09
```

So, the range of [-4,4] seems to be better than other.

**Question:** Is there a way to find the proper limits of weigths and biases compared to temperature limits and temperature decrease rate?

Note: Im trying two ways here. First is **randomizing all weights and biases at once** for each trial. Second is **randomizing only single weight and a single bias** at each trial. (50 iterations before decreasing temperature). Single weight change gives worse results.

```
 (n+1) is next value, (n) is the value before

 TempMax=2.0
 TempMin=0.1 ----->approaching to zero, error of XOR output approaches to zero too
 Temp(n+1)=Temp(n)/1.001

 Weight update:
 w(n+1)=w(n)+(float)(Math.random()*t*2.0f-t*1.0f)); // t is temperature
 (same for bias update)

 Iterations per temperature=50

 Using java's Math.random() method(Spectral property is appropriate for annealing?)

 Transition probability:
 (1.0f/(1.0f+Math.exp(((candidate state error)-(old error))/temp)))

 Neuron activation function: Math.tanh()
```

Tried many times and results are nearly same. Is **reannealing** the only solution to evade deeper local minimums?

I need a suitable weight/bias range/limit according to total neuron number and layer number and starting/enging temperature. 3x6x5x6x1 can count 3-bit input and gives outpu, can approximate step function, but I need to play with ranges always.

For this training data set, output error is too big(193 data points, 2 inputs, 1 output):

193 2 1 
0.499995 0.653846 
1 
0.544418 0.481604 
1 
0.620200 0.320118 
1 
0.595191 0.404816 
0 
0.404809 0.595184 
1 
0.171310 0.636142 
0 
0.014323 0.403392 
0 
0.617884 0.476556 
0 
0.391548 0.478424 
1 
0.455912 0.721618 
0 
0.615385 0.500005 
0 
0.268835 0.268827 
0 
0.812761 0.187243 
0 
0.076923 0.499997 
1 
0.769231 0.500006 
0 
0.650862 0.864223 
0 
0.799812 0.299678 
1 
0.328106 0.614848 
0 
0.591985 0.722088 
0 
0.692308 0.500005 
1 
0.899757 0.334418 
0 
0.484058 0.419839 
1 
0.200188 0.700322 
0 
0.863769 0.256940 
0 
0.384615 0.499995 
1 
0.457562 0.508439 
0 
0.515942 0.580161 
0 
0.844219 0.431535 
1 
0.456027 0.529379 
0 
0.235571 0.104252 
0 
0.260149 0.400644 
1 
0.500003 0.423077 
1 
0.544088 0.278382 
1 
0.597716 0.540480 
0 
0.562549 0.651021 
1 
0.574101 0.127491 
1 
0.545953 0.731052 
0 
0.649585 0.350424 
1 
0.607934 0.427886 
0 
0.499995 0.807692 
1 
0.437451 0.348979 
0 
0.382116 0.523444 
1 
1 0.500000 
1 
0.731165 0.731173 
1 
0.500002 0.038462 
0 
0.683896 0.536585 
1 
0.910232 0.581604 
0 
0.499998 0.961538 
1 
0.903742 0.769772 
1 
0.543973 0.470621 
1 
0.593481 0.639914 
1 
0.240659 0.448408 
1 
0.425899 0.872509 
0 
0 0.500000 
0 
0.500006 0.269231 
1 
0.155781 0.568465 
0 
0.096258 0.230228 
0 
0.583945 0.556095 
0 
0.550746 0.575954 
0 
0.680302 0.935290 
1 
0.693329 0.461550 
1 
0.500005 0.192308 
0 
0.230769 0.499994 
1 
0.721691 0.831791 
0 
0.621423 0.793156 
1 
0.735853 0.342415 
0 
0.402284 0.459520 
1 
0.589105 0.052045 
0 
0.189081 0.371208 
0 
0.533114 0.579952 
0 
0.251594 0.871762 
1 
0.764429 0.895748 
1 
0.499994 0.730769 
0 
0.415362 0.704317 
0 
0.422537 0.615923 
1 
0.337064 0.743842 
1 
0.560960 0.806496 
1 
0.810919 0.628792 
1 
0.319698 0.064710 
0 
0.757622 0.393295 
0 
0.577463 0.384077 
0 
0.349138 0.135777 
1 
0.165214 0.433402 
0 
0.241631 0.758362 
0 
0.118012 0.341772 
1 
0.514072 0.429271 
1 
0.676772 0.676781 
0 
0.294328 0.807801 
0 
0.153846 0.499995 
0 
0.500005 0.346154 
0 
0.307692 0.499995 
0 
0.615487 0.452168 
0 
0.466886 0.420048 
1 
0.440905 0.797064 
1 
0.485928 0.570729 
0 
0.470919 0.646174 
1 
0.224179 0.315696 
0 
0.439040 0.193504 
0 
0.408015 0.277912 
1 
0.316104 0.463415 
0 
0.278309 0.168209 
1 
0.214440 0.214435 
1 
0.089768 0.418396 
1 
0.678953 0.767832 
1 
0.080336 0.583473 
1 
0.363783 0.296127 
1 
0.474240 0.562183 
0 
0.313445 0.577267 
0 
0.416055 0.443905 
1 
0.529081 0.353826 
0 
0.953056 0.687662 
1 
0.534725 0.448035 
1 
0.469053 0.344394 
0 
0.759341 0.551592 
0 
0.705672 0.192199 
1 
0.385925 0.775385 
1 
0.590978 0.957385 
1 
0.406519 0.360086 
0 
0.409022 0.042615 
0 
0.264147 0.657585 
1 
0.758369 0.241638 
1 
0.622380 0.622388 
1 
0.321047 0.232168 
0 
0.739851 0.599356 
0 
0.555199 0.366750 
0 
0.608452 0.521576 
0 
0.352098 0.401168 
0 
0.530947 0.655606 
1 
0.160045 0.160044 
0 
0.455582 0.518396 
0 
0.881988 0.658228 
0 
0.643511 0.153547 
1 
0.499997 0.576923 
0 
0.575968 0.881942 
0 
0.923077 0.500003 
0 
0.449254 0.424046 
1 
0.839782 0.727039 
0 
0.647902 0.598832 
1 
0.444801 0.633250 
1 
0.392066 0.572114 
1 
0.242378 0.606705 
1 
0.136231 0.743060 
1 
0.711862 0.641568 
0 
0.834786 0.566598 
1 
0.846154 0.500005 
1 
0.538462 0.500002 
1 
0.379800 0.679882 
0 
0.584638 0.295683 
1 
0.459204 0.540793 
0 
0.331216 0.430082 
0 
0.672945 0.082478 
0 
0.671894 0.385152 
1 
0.046944 0.312338 
0 
0.499995 0.884615 
0 
0.542438 0.491561 
1 
0.540796 0.459207 
1 
0.828690 0.363858 
1 
0.785560 0.785565 
0 
0.686555 0.422733 
1 
0.231226 0.553456 
1 
0.465275 0.551965 
0 
0.378577 0.206844 
0 
0.567988 0.567994 
0 
0.668784 0.569918 
1 
0.384513 0.547832 
1 
0.288138 0.358432 
1 
0.432012 0.432006 
1 
0.424032 0.118058 
1 
0.296023 0.703969 
1 
0.525760 0.437817 
1 
0.748406 0.128238 
0 
0.775821 0.684304 
1 
0.919664 0.416527 
0 
0.327055 0.917522 
1 
0.985677 0.596608 
1 
0.356489 0.846453 
0 
0.500005 0.115385 
1 
0.377620 0.377612 
0 
0.559095 0.202936 
0 
0.410895 0.947955 
1 
0.187239 0.812757 
1 
0.768774 0.446544 
0 
0.614075 0.224615 
0 
0.350415 0.649576 
0 
0.160218 0.272961 
1 
0.454047 0.268948 
1 
0.306671 0.538450 
0 
0.323228 0.323219 
1 
0.839955 0.839956 
1 
0.636217 0.703873 
0 
0.703977 0.296031 
0 
0.662936 0.256158 
0 
0.100243 0.665582 
1

Comment: Approximated step-function, made a 3-bit digital-to-analog net, XOR wasnt a problem but just couldnt solve the **two-spirals problem**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly doubt that any strict rules exist for your problem. First of all, limits/bounds of weights are strictly dependant on your input data representation, activation functions, neurons number and output function. what you can rely on here are rules of the thumb in the best possible scenario.

First, lets consider the initial weights values in classical algorithms. Some basic idea of the weights scale are to use them in the range of `[-1,1]` for small layers, and for large ones divide it by the square root of the number of units in the large layer. More sophisticated methods are described by [Bishop (1995)](http://books.google.pl/books/about/Neural_Networks_for_Pattern_Recognition.html?id=-aAwQO_-rXwC&redir_esc=y). With such rule of the thumb we could deduce, that a resonable range (which is simply row of magniture bigger then the initial guess) would be something in the form of `[-10,10]/sqrt(neurons_count_in_the_lower_layer)`.

Unfortunately, to my best knowledge, temperature choice is much more complex, as it is rather a **data dependant** factor, not just topology based one. In some papers there have been suggestions for some values for some specific time series prediction, but nothing general. In simmulated annleaing "in general" (not just applied to NN training), there have been proposed many heuristic choices, ie.

> If we know the maximum distance (cost function difference) between one
>   neighbour and another then we can use this information to calculate a
>   starting temperature. Another method, suggested in (13. Rayward-Smith, V.J., Osman, I.H., Reeves, C.R., Smith, G.D. 1996. Modern Heuristic Search Methods. John Wiley & Sons.), is to start with a very high temperature and cool it rapidly
>   until about 60% of worst solutions are being accepted. This forms the
>   real starting temperature and it can now be cooled more slowly. A
>   similar idea, suggested in (5. Dowsland, K.A. 1995. Simulated Annealing. In Modern Heuristic Techniques for Combinatorial Problems (ed. Reeves, C.R.), McGraw-Hill, 1995), is to rapidly heat the
>   system until a certain proportion of worse solutions are accepted and
>   then slow cooling can start. This can be seen to be similar to how
>   physical annealing works in that the material is heated until it is
>   liquid and then cooling begins (i.e. once the material is a liquid it
>   is pointless carrying on heating it). [*from notes from University of Nottingham*]

But the choice of the best for your application has to be based on numerous tests, as most of the things in the machine learning. If you are dealing with the problem, where you are really concerned about well trained neural network, it seems resonable to interest in **Extreme Machine Learning**, and **Extreme Learning Machines (ELM)**, where the neural network training is conducted in the **global optimization** procedure, which guarantees the best possible solution (under used regularized cost function). Simulated annleaing, as a interative, greedy process (as well as back propagation) cannot guarantee anything, there are only heuristics and rules of thumb.

Comment: So each layer's neurons can have different weight boundaries and the boundary length can be dependent to square-root of the **number of inputs of those neurons** or their own layer's size?

Comment: Yes, each layer can have different scale, as it is correlated with the size of the signal, and the reasonable interval in the activation function they should fall into. The bounds i've given are based on the number of neurons from which connections go up. So in 3 layered network Input-Hidden-Output, the weights between Input and Hidden should be based on the number of Input neurons, and between Hidden and Output on the number of Hidden ones.

Comment: What about bias? That Randomized too?

Comment: bias can be treated as additional neuron - assuming that your input data is standarized (has mean 0 and std 1, or at least falls into [-1,1]) then it should be sufficient to treat its boundaries as weights boundaries. But it would be more "safe" to give it wider (even of row of magniture) interval, as it plays crucial role in the universal approximator capabilities of NN.